# Media query for responsive grid using grid-area

Tags: css

I'm a CSS newbie and have been exploring w3schools, playing with their sample code. I tried to make a grid responsive by adjusting the `grid-area` in a media query, but it's not having any effect when I size the viewport up to 600+px. What am I missing?

Here's a link: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G87J3CAFWM69

Edit: Here is the code without a link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
.header { grid-area: header; }
.menu { grid-area: menu; }
.main { grid-area: main; }
.right { grid-area: right; }
.footer { grid-area: footer; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header' 'menu' 'main' 'right' 'footer';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header header header'
    'menu main main main right right'
    'menu footer footer footer footer footer';
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The grid-area Property</h1>

<p>You can use the <em>grid-area</em> property to name grid items.</p>

<p>You can refer to the name when you set up the grid layout, by using the <em>grid-template-areas</em> property on the grid container.</p>

<p>This grid layout contains six columns and three rows:</p>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="menu">Menu</div>
  <div class="main">Main</div>  
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please copy the code here (external links may disappear in the future). In addition, I'd avoid w3schools like the plague if I were you. Use the Mozilla documentation instead.

Comment: Thank you, Acorn. I have posted the code inline - does this help?

Comment: Update - MistaPrime's answer solved my question :)

Comment: Much better, thank you. If MistaPrimer's answer solved your question, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS does not have any classes, you are calling a class `grid-template-areas` that does not exist.

The responsive CSS should look something like this:

`@media (max-width: 600px) {
.grid-container:
    width:400px;
}
}`

That CSS basically says that on all screens that are up to 600px, therefore all screens below 600px it will render the class called `.grid-container` to be 400px wide.

Comment: Thank you so much, MistaPrime! I was attempting to call the `grid-template-areas` property, but I now see that it wasn't tied to a selector. By tying it to the .grid-container class, my problem was solved.